# Why does PHP sometimes return a blank page without an error?

Tags: php

I use PHP for programming contests (bad choice, I know. But it's the only language I'm good at). Often, when I create a very large variable, PHP returns a blank page. No errors are generated.

For example, if I have a script like this:

```
<?php
echo 'test';

$var=array();
for($i=0;$i<9999999999;$i++){
  $var[]=$i*9999999999;
}
```

No output would be outputted; not even the "test".

Is there a way to prevent this?

P.S. The script usually terminates quickly, in about 2-3 seconds. Which leads me to think that PHP is terminating the script without reaching the end.

Comment: You may have reached the `max_execution_time`. Depending on how output buffering is configured, you may not see the `test`

Comment: For your script I see the `test` output (I run it in console) and after that php goes thinking. There is absolutely no reason for contest scripts to be run in browser

Comment: have you tested with looping like say 5 times only? are you accessing PHP on a server (not accessing the file directly)? are you sure you are on the right page? try writing words outside the `<?php` to make sure you ARE on the right page

Comment: Try using PHP on the command line, if it is your favorite. Much easier than dealing with the browser/server. http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More than likely you are getting a

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted
```

There are a few things that can be done to change this as well as to display the error.   One is to either change error reporting in your php.ini file or to add

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

at the top of your code.  The second would be increase the allowed size.

You are using a lot of memory trying to multiply this large of a number that many times.  What is the reason you are trying to do this?  Is there a different way you might be able to do the same thing?

Here are a few resources you can use

to increase the size http://www.mydigitallife.info/php-allowed-memory-size-exchausted-fatal-error/

Error Reporting  http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

If you do not need i to go that high (9999999999) seems really high.  Reduce the size.

Another issue you may be having is

```
Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded
```

You can always increase the execution time if you have to.

Max execution time http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

also [Increase max execution time for php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739870/increase-max-execution-time-for-php)

Really all this depends on what error you are getting and by starting with showing the error reporting, this will help determine what the real issue at hand is.