# Running youtube-dl with php exec

Tags: php, youtube-dl

I am trying to fetch video details as JSON using PHP `exec()`

I have `youtube-dl` installed on my CentOS server.

Running `youtube-dl -J <VideoURL>` via `SSH`/`Terminal` just works fine.

My `test.php` script returns empty page :(

```
echo exec("youtube-dl -J <VideoURL>");
//Installed via pip

//OR

echo exec("python /home/site/youtube-dl -J <VideoURL>");
//Downloaded as file named youtube-dl
```

`exec` is enabled if I test it like:

```
if(function_exists('exec')) {
    echo "exec is enabled";
}
```

`IP` of server is not blocked by YouTube as i am able to successfully run command via terminal

Comment: If you want PHP to return you the console output of your command, use `shell_exec` instead of `exec`

Comment: @Bitz i've tried both, no result.

Comment: You could be hitting an error, which are hidden by default. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476233/why-does-php-sometimes-return-a-blank-page-without-an-error

I tried what you are trying to achieve and got it working properly, I will provide the code inside my test.php in an Answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve what you are by doing the following in my `test.php` file

```
<?php

if(function_exists('shell_exec')) {
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo shell_exec("youtube-dl -J https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zGDzdps75ns");
}

?>
```

Comment: I have tested this before, nothing worked. I don't know how this is working fine.
Thank you.

Comment: The only noteworthy difference I can see between the code you provided and mine are the <?php ?> tags around the code, but if those were not included, the contents of the file would have been output in plain text. Very strange. Glad you got it working. :)

Comment: No, they were there before. I am also confused. It is even working with `exec()` as of now.