# Php curl timing out despite setting both connecttimeout and timeout

Tags: php, curl, timeout, php-5.3

I have set the following:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
```

before calling `curl_exec($ch)`

However, every now and then, I get an error: `GOT AN ERROR<br/>Operation timed out after 10002 milliseconds with 0 bytes received<br/>-------<br/>`

Seems curl is not respecting the timeout settings. I tried setting the _MS versions also, but to no avail. Please help!

Comment: Maybe the server you connect to has a timeout?

Comment: @Niels: Interesting... any ideas how can I check? The results are unpredictable as of now.

Comment: @workwise have you got and htaccess file? update the timeout there.

Comment: @Tauseef Yes, actually I have access to both the calling server and the server I connect to. Can you tell me where exactly I need to put the timeout in which htaccess - I haven't done it before.

Comment: Also, I feel 1000 ms is bit too low for apache settings (I hear default is 300)

Answer (score 1):

.htAccess are able to override a subset of the server's global configuration for the directory that they are in, and all sub-directories.

find the property `max_execution_time` in the .htaccess of your website. this time is in seconds as I remember.

**EDIT:** Also check the PHP.ini file

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value post_max_size 5M
php_value upload_max_filesize 5M
php_value memory_limit 300M
php_value max_execution_time 259200
php_value max_input_time 259200
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1200
</IfModule>
```

[Increase max execution time for php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739870/increase-max-execution-time-for-php)