# An AJAX HTTP error Code: 200 while migrating from wordpress to drupal

Tags: ajax, wordpress, drupal, drupal-7

I am getting this error [image] while migrating my site from

### wordpress to drupal 7 using migration tool.

how to resolve this ??
I have tried updating the drupal_set_time_limit() to some bigger value(1800) in /includes/locale.inc but it didn't help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have to increase the timeout value in your php.ini file. Drupal can't set the limit higher than PHP's maximum.

Comment: Could there be another limit set in an .htaccess file?

Comment: nope and why would there be a timeout limit in **.htaccess file** ??

Comment: @Sam, there are several places to set the time limit. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739870/increase-max-execution-time-for-php has a good overview