# PHP - Download multiple files with big size

Tags: php, file, http, download

I've created a photo book and I want that the users can download all the album with the respective photo but the problem is that some album have the size of 5GB and, if I compress all the photos to a zip file, the server block the request because it need too much time.

How can resolve this problem?

Is possible download multiple files without compress all into a zip file?

If yes, How?

PS: I cant modify the php.ini

Comment: What web server is this on, apache? Do you have htaccess availability?

Comment: yes, the website is hosted on one.com

Comment: are these jpg photos? don't compress those. you'll waste a TON of cpu time and achieve at best only a couple % compression. just zip them as is - e.g. use zip as a container, and not a compression system.

Comment: how is possible don't compress it? can you write an example?

Answer (score 0):

If timeout is your only problem, then within PHP you can use:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
```

Or, if on Apache and you have htaccess availability:

```
php_value max_execution_time 300
```

[Here is a great post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739870/increase-max-execution-time-for-php) on other examples useful if using Wordpress etc.

Zipping an unknown number of files into a 5GB+ archive sounds nasty, but that's the solution to yoru question above :) I hope you have protection against a user sitting there hitting refresh because they got impatient?

Comment: nothing to do, this host no support .htaccess and ini_set

Comment: ... then you're up a creek without a paddle. You'll have to work with the time restriction you have (the default 30 seconds I assume). Limiting the number of photos per archive seems the best approach.