# Max Execution Time for Session Start (Wordpress Upload)

Tags: wordpress, function, upload, execution-time, genesis

I'm wondering if there is a code for `functions.php` that can increase upload size for files once is required by user session. I need to increase this limit only when the user requests to upload a file, not in the `php.ini` or `.htaccess` as general rule (for security issues).

Example:
A user must upload one file of 250 MB or 5 files of 50 MB without having time outs.

My `.htaccess` limits are:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 16M
php_value post_max_size 16M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
```

I'm using Wordpress 4.4.2 with Genesis Child theme.

I need some code in `functions.php` that can increase temporarily this limit on session start of each upload request. Thank you for you time! Hope to find someone that know this trick.

Cheers! :-)
Daniel

Comment: This question is already answered here [max execution time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739870/increase-max-execution-time-for-php)

Answer (score 1):

Please try following lines in functions.php

@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '250M' );

@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '250M' );

@ini_set( 'max_execution_time', '1000' );

Answer (score 0):

**1) for function.php file**

@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '64M' );

@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '64M');

@ini_set( 'max_execution_time', '300' );

**2) for php.ini file**

upload_max_filesize = 64M

post_max_size = 64M

max_execution_time = 300

**3) for .htaccess file**

php_value upload_max_filesize 64M

php_value post_max_size 64M

php_value max_execution_time 300

php_value max_input_time 300