# Cannot increase PHP max_execution_time on OVH Perso Hosting

Tags: php, codeigniter, ovh

I have hosted my codeIgniter application on OVH Perso Hosting but when people are trying to fill a form with multiple files, the page expires before the end of uploading and becomes a blank page.
i have tried to change the MAX_EXECUTION_TIME by using .htaccess or ini_set directly in the code but it doesn't work.
i need your help to know what i can do to allow people to submit their forms without any trouble. Thank you.

Comment: Not every shared hosting provider will _allow_ you to change those settings - so go check their documentation/FAQ. // `max_execution_time` might not be the setting that needs modifying here in the first place. _“the page expires before the end of uploading and becomes a blank page”_ - then your first step should be to find out what error actually occurred, by checking the relevant errors logs (provided, you have access.)

Comment: Did you try <IfModule mod_php5.c> from this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739870/increase-max-execution-time-for-php

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this code in controller construct

```
public function __construct() {
 parent::__construct();
 ini_set('max_execution_time', 900);
 ini_set('memory_limit','1024M');
}
```

if not working try to create a file `.ovhconfig` and paste this code

```
app.engine=php
app.engine.version=7.1
http.firewall=none
environment=production
```