# Maximum execution time of 20 seconds exceeded

Tags: laravel, google-api

I am getting this error during google  auth redirect,Any idea how to resolve this issue here  is image show error when tried to sign in with google account using`

[image: Error image]

Comment: Can you show us the code where you're making the request?

Comment: Thanks for  respond,the situation is when I run via localhost is working good but when I try to run in live server it load then give that error

Comment: Have you tracked how long it actually takes on your localhost then? Is it more than 20 seconds? And for the live environment, are you using other credentials or such?

Comment: you are showing nothing on the question, but maybe you have to extend the timeout time,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739870/increase-max-execution-time-for-php

Answer (score 0):

Its a php server configuration issue. You would have to extend the max execution time of your server. Also, try to figure out what script you are running that takes so long. Normally, one script shouldn't run that long without responding to the user.

Try creating a job for the task or running it as a command.

[Change Max Execution Time](https://www.simplified.guide/php/increase-max-execution-time)

[Laravel Jobs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queues)

[Commands](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/scheduling)